# Visual editor for xslt

Tags: xml

I was wondering if it is included in Ubuntu any GUI tool to support the creation of xslt -- bonus points if it also shows how it transforms some reference xml source as I write the xslt document.

I've had a look in apt-cache search but cannot find anything related, although it sounds weird to me that there is nothing for doing that...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is nothing for free. If you are interested in paying for program that visualises transformation then there are options. Although it's not very productive as you may expect. Better do it by hand

Comment: Check if Serna Free can do what you want: http://www.syntext.com/products/serna-free/

Comment: After I saw provided answer (emacs), thought that maybe I did not understood you right. I had impression that you are looking for XSLT mappers. If you just want to validate your transformation then there are lot of CLI tools which you can integrate in your preferred editor

Comment: @zetah, I suppose you got me right -- I am learning xslt, so I am looking for something that gives me very quick feedback about how changing the xslt affects the output xml.

Comment: OK then, as mentioned mappers like xsl:easy (Google for others) are expensive and good looking, but I don't find them productive. Suggested Serna is really nice, and good to have it, but again I would suggest to you to use tools like `xsltproc`, `xmllint`... with your preferred editor.

Answer (score 1):

`emacs` has a mode for everything.  http://xslt-process.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 1):

Treebeard provides a lightweight IDE for xslt, with integrated transformation.

http://treebeard.sourceforge.net/